# Angular 9 app bug: material cards grid is not responsive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, responsive

I am working on a Contacts app with Angular 9. The **list** component displays, for each contact, some info and an image, in a card.

In `app\components\list\list.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ContactsListService } from '../../services/contacts-list.service';
import { Contact } from '../../models/Contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  contactsList:Contact[];

  ngVersion: string = VERSION.full;
  matVersion: string = '5.1.0';
  columns: number;

  constructor(private ContactsListService:ContactsListService) { }

   // Cards
   breakPoints() {
    switch(true) {
        case (window.innerWidth <= 480):
          this.columns = 1;
          break;
        case (window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth <= 992):
          this.columns = 4;
          break;
        default:
          this.columns = 6;
      }
    }

  ngOnInit(): void  {
    // Contact list
    this.ContactsListService.getContcts().subscribe(
      contactsList => { this.contactsList = contactsList },
      error => { }
    );

    this.breakPoints();

  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.breakPoints();
  }

}
```

In `app\components\list\list.component.html` I have:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" rowHeight="300px" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let contact of contactsList">
        <mat-card>
                <mat-card-header>
                    <img mat-card-avatar src="{{contact.picture.thumbnail}}">
                    <mat-card-title>{{contact.name.first}} {{contact.name.last}}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>From {{contact.location.city}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                        <img mat-card-image src="{{contact.picture.medium}}" alt="{{contact.name.first}} {{contact.name.last}}">
                <mat-card-content>
                        <h3>{{contact.location.city}}, {{contact.location.country}}</h3>
                </mat-card-content>
                    <mat-card-actions>
                        <button mat-button> CONTACT </button>
                    </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

The list of cards is intended to be **responsive** (and the *cards should wrapp*), but it is not.

In fact, the **tiles are full with** at all resolutions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're doing nothing wrong. `mat-card` follows material design specs and it demands some fixed spacing on headers, footers, margins, paddings, etc, *in a non-responsive way*. So if the card and all its sections (title, subtitle, image, footer, font size along with the minimum distances) doesn't fit in the space, it'll cross the limits of the container. If you need a different behavior, you can build your own responsive card layout completely contained in `mat-card-content`. Or you'll need to override some material specs.

Comment: Yeah, he fixed the tile row height. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained a satisfying results this way:

In `app\components\list\list.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ContactsListService } from '../../services/contacts-list.service';
import { Contact } from '../../models/Contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  contactsList:Contact[];

  ngVersion: string = VERSION.full;
  matVersion: string = '5.1.0';
  columns: number;

  constructor(private ContactsListService:ContactsListService) { }

   // Cards
   breakPoints() {
    switch(true) {
        case (window.innerWidth <= 480):
          this.columns = 1;
          break;
        case (window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth <= 640):
          this.columns = 2;
          break;
        case (window.innerWidth > 640 && window.innerWidth <= 992):
          this.columns = 3;
          break;
        default:
          this.columns = 5;
      }
    }

  ngOnInit(): void  {
    // Contact list
    this.ContactsListService.getContcts().subscribe(
      contactsList => { this.contactsList = contactsList },
      error => { }
    );
    this.breakPoints();
  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.breakPoints();
  }
}
```

In `app\components\list\list.component.html` I have:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" rowHeight="500px" style="padding:10px" [gutterSize]="'10px'" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
    <mat-grid-tile fxFlexAlign="stretch" *ngFor="let contact of contactsList">
        <mat-card style="width: 100%; height: 90%">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <img mat-card-avatar src="{{contact.picture.thumbnail}}">
                    <mat-card-title>{{contact.name.first}} {{contact.name.last}}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>From {{contact.location.city}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                        <img mat-card-image src="{{contact.picture.large}}" alt="{{contact.name.first}} {{contact.name.last}}">
                <mat-card-content>
                        <h3>{{contact.location.city}}, {{contact.location.country}}</h3>
                </mat-card-content>
                    <mat-card-actions>
                        <button mat-button color="primary"> CONTACT </button>
                    </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Result screenshot:

[image]